# Downloading images from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage, memorystream

I'm writing a program that can download images from specified file paths from our Azure Storage container.

I have put together the following function from code found online and then removing the errors. However, the final errors I can't get rid of.

Full code below:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.IO;
namespace WarehousePhotoProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string storageConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("storageconnectionstring");

    public Form1()


       {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DownloadFileFromBlob(string fileName, string containerName)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(storageConnectionString));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(fileName);
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            blob.DownloadToStream(memStream);
            Response.ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + fileName.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", blob.Properties.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());

        }
    }
   }
```

The code currently errors on `RoleEnvironment` saying the namespace doesn't exist, am I missing an assembly reference? Or do I need to import another `using`. The second error is on all of the `Result.` again stating `Response` doesn't exist.

Is this also the best approach to take regarding downloading images from BlobStorage or should I take another approach at it?

EDIT: I resolved the `RoleEnvironment` error with the help of the given answer. Now trying to determine what the Response section of the code needs changing too.

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //_storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);

        DownloadFileFromBlob("029000/1.png", "warehouseimages", "Desktop");
    }

    private void DownloadFileFromBlob(string fileName, string containerName, string localFilePath)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(fileName);
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(localFilePath))
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download images to local disk, your code could be modified as below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Download File From Blob
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">For example: image.PNG</param>
    /// <param name="containerName">container name of blob</param>
    /// <param name="localFilePath">For example: @"C:\Test\BlobTest.PNG"</param>
    private void DownloadFileFromBlob(string fileName, string containerName, string localFilePath)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Your connection string");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(fileName);
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(localFilePath))
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code runs without error, however, the image is not appearing in the filePath I specify... I've added the code I'm now running to my Q any ideas let me know.

Comment: Ignore me, was looking in the wrong location for it.

Answer (score 2):

The RoleEnvironment class is part of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime namespace which I know from the old classic Cloud Services.

You should probably use the **ConfigurationManager** to retrieve your settings.

See [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration) or if you use the .NET full framework read more about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Okay, I've resolved that error thanks. Any idea on what the Response bit needs changing to?

Comment: You're working in a WinForms application, right? Ditch the entire `Response` part and save the MemoryStream to file.

Comment: rickvdbosch was faster then me and is right since you don't have a Request / Response from an API but want to save the file.